# Codename One: SQLite connection errors

Tags: sqlite, database-connection, codenameone

I am trying to connect an SQLite database (saved in the app folder) to a picker component (accepting strings). The following is the code I used (previously advised):

```
Database db = null;
Cursor cur = null;
try {
    db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("FoodAndBeverage.db");
    if(selectItem.getText().startsWith("Still Water")) {
        cur = db.executeQuery(selectItem.getText());
        int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
        addItem.removeAll();
        if(columns > 0) {
            boolean next = cur.next();
            if(next) {
                ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                    columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                }
                while(next) {
                    Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                    String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                    }
                    data.add(currentRowArray);
                    next = cur.next();
                }
                Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                data.toArray(arr);
                addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr)));
            } else {
                addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
            }
        } else {
            addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
        }
    } else {
        db.execute(selectItem.getText());
        addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query completed successfully");
    }
    addItem.revalidate();
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
    addItem.removeAll();
    addItem.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Error: " + err);
    addItem.revalidate();
} finally {
    Util.cleanup(db);
    Util.cleanup(cur);
}
```

However, I get the following error messages:

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Exception: java.io.IOException - [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)
at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:886)
at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:897)
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:864)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:207)
at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:50)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:616)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:606)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:578)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEDatabase.execute(SEDatabase.java:90)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.AddItem(MyApplication.java:88)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1147)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.io.IOException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEDatabase.execute(SEDatabase.java:94)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.AddItem(MyApplication.java:88)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1147)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1147)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Layout doesn't support adding with arguments: com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout
at com.codename1.ui.layouts.Layout.addLayoutComponent(Layout.java:64)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.addComponent(Container.java:525)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.add(Container.java:172)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.add(Container.java:201)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.AddItem(MyApplication.java:95)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:145)
... 9 more
```

This may be due to the app not recognising the database. To clarify, where does the database file need to be saved? I have currently saved the file in the app folder.
[View of app folder showing where the database file (highlighted) is saved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDimN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the right place where the database should be stored. If you need the database shipped with your app e.g. this from [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html):

> Some SQLite apps ship with a "ready made" database. We allow you to
>   replace the DB file by using the code:
>
> ```
> String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(“databaseName”);
> ```
>
> You can then use the `FileSystemStorage` class to write the content of
>   your DB file into the path. Notice that it must be a valid SQLite
>   file!

The physical location is under the .cn1 directory in the users home dir. The `java.home` value for your OS.